# How to dissolve touching polylines

Tags: line, clip, merge, dissolve, length

I want to dissolve some polylines clipped in a series of polygons, but since there are different polylines in the polygons, I cannot dissolve those with the attributes of polygons. For example in the picture below, if I dissolve it based on the polygon it will result in a single row in the table of attributes, while I want two different rows.[image: example] I need the length of polylines so please tell me if any solution works. Is there a function that dissolves the polylines only if they are touching?

Comment: Which software is that ?

Comment: Your goal is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This workflow works in QGIS, but should in principle be the same in any software:

1. Select all and dissolve.
2. Run Multipart to single parts.